# ag-grid paste functionality not working in cell textbox

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to enable paste feature in `ag-grid` cell with in textbox. I have tried with `Ctrl+V` and also with right click **Paste** fuctionality but it is show disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As stated in AG-Grid documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-clipboard/)

> The 'paste' operation in the context menu is not possible and hence
>   always disabled. It is not possible because of a browser security
>   restriction that Javascript cannot take data from the clipboard
>   without the user explicitly doing a paste command from the browser (eg
>   Ctrl+V or from the browser menu). If Javascript could do this, then
>   websites could steal data from the client via grabbing from the
>   clipboard maliciously. The reason why ag-Grid keeps the paste in the
>   menu as disabled is to indicate to the user that paste is possible and
>   it provides the shortcut as a hint to the user. This is also why the
>   API cannot copy from clipboard.

So you can't use the paste functionality from the context menu unfortunately.
However the Ctrl + V should work.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have also tried with Ctrl + V but its not working.

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr with the code you’re running?

Comment: Sorry :(.. code is purely dynamic and can't able to made with plnkr